# Recursividade para retornar números de 0 até n

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer uma função recursiva que retorne os `n` números de `0` até `n`, meu código ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int imprimenumeros(int n){

    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return  imprimenumeros(n-1);
}

void main (){
    int n;
    int y;
    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", imprimenumeros (n) );
}
```

Mas não está funcionando... onde está o erro?

Comment: primeiro coloca o código, depois seleciona ele todo e aperta ctrl+k que ele formata pra vc, no inicio eu me enrolava pra botar codigo aqui mas esse jeito é o mais simples.

Comment: Obrigada pela dica!

Comment: Já estou escrevendo a resposta pra vc, é bem simples, vc errou em um pequeno detalhe

Comment: Não entendi, porque quando digito 1 o resultado é 0 e 1, quando digito 2 o resultado é 0, 1 e 2. O exercício pedi para que fale se o número é primo ou não.

Answer (score 9):

Uma pequena correção, você quer que retorne de N até 0 e não de 0 até N, visto que vc está **decrementando** recursivamente, caso queira mesmo que vá de 0 até N eu altero o código.

Outra coisa que você esqueceu é que você não está imprimindo os números, está apenas dando return, ou seja, ele executa todo o cálculo mas não imprime.

Outra observação é que se quer que comece a partir do 0 então vc tem de trocar 1 por zero no seu primeiro if:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int imprimenumeros(int n){
        printf("%d\n", n );
        if (n==0){
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return  imprimenumeros(n-1);
        }
    } 
void main (){ 
    int n; 
    int y; 
    printf("digite um numero\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &n); 
    imprimenumeros (n);

}
```

Agora caso você queira mesmo fazer incremental de 0 até um N dado, basta você passar a sua variável inicial "nesse caso é o 0" juntamente com a sua variável terminal "que nesse caso é o N" e incrementar recursivamente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int imprimenumeros(int n, int y){

        printf("%d\n", y);
        if (n>y){
            return imprimenumeros(n, y+1);
        }
        else {
            return 0 ;
        }
    } 
void main (){ 
    int n; 
    int y = 0; 
    printf("digite um numero\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &n); 
    imprimenumeros (n, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendi! Brigada! Mas e se for o contrario de 0 até n?

Comment: Qualquer outra dúvida na implementação é só perguntar :)

Comment: aí é mais fácil, é só vc guardar o n e fazer ncrementando de 0 até n

Comment: @Lucy coloquei o código caso você queira a outra opção, que é incrementar ao invés de decrementar e dei uma rápida explicação da lógica tbm :)

Comment: Não entendi, porque quando digito 1 o resultado é 0 e 1, quando digito 2 o resultado é 0, 1 e 2. O exercício pedi para que fale se o número é primo ou não.

Answer (score 8):

Você fala em **retornar** os números de 0 a N, mas sua função chama `imprimenumeros`, então estou assumindo que pra você basta *imprimir na tela* os números dessa função, estou certo? (caso contrário, seria necessário armazenar a lista de números em um array ou similar, o que é um pouquinho mais complicado...) Afinal, uma função que retorna um `int` só retorna um único valor, para retornar vários seria necessária uma outra estrutura de dados.

Uma maneira de fazer isso diferente das demais respostas é primeiro fazendo a chamada recursiva e *depois* imprimindo o número:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void imprimenumeros(int n){
    if (n > 0)
        imprimenumeros(n-1);
    printf("%d\n", n);
}

void main (){
    int n;
    int y;
    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    imprimenumeros (n);
}
```

Assim, quando ele for imprimir o `n` ele já vai ter impresso o `n-1` (na chamada recursiva), então a ordem das impressões será crescente de 0 a N.

Comment: Não entendi, porque quando digito 1 o resultado é 0 e 1, quando digito 2 o resultado é 0, 1 e 2. O exercício pedi para que fale se o número é primo ou não.

Answer (score 7):

Se o que quer é imprimir os números, a função imprimenumeros pode retornar **void**. O que vc faz agora é fazer printf no inicio da função, ver se **n** é zero,

1) se não for chama a mesma função (recursivamente),

2) se for então retorna vazio (daí o return;).

No final do método main vc retorna 0, para indicar ao sistema operativo que o aplicativo terminou corretamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void imprimenumeros(int n){
    printf("%d\n", n);
    if (n==0) {
        return;
    } else {
        imprimenumeros(n-1);
    }
}

int main (){
    int n;
    int y;
    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    imprimenumeros(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Deixo aqui o mesmo problema resolvido utilizando o método da **iteração**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void imprimenumeros(int n){
    while(n >= 0) {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        n = n - 1; // ou n--;
    }
    return;
}

int main (){
    int n;
    int y;
    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    imprimenumeros(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Brigada! Mas n vi onde errei :/

Comment: Se o que quer é imprimir os números, a função imprimenumeros pode retornar void.

O que vc faz agora é fazer printf no inicio da função, ver se n é zero, se não for chama a mesma função (recursivamente), se for então retorna vazio (daí o return;).

No final do método main vc retorna 0, para indicar ao sistema operativo que o aplicativo terminou correctamente.

Editei a resposta acima.

Comment: Então um `while(n != 0)` poderia ser considerada um tipo de recursividade?

Comment: Não. Recursividade é quando vc define uma função à custa de si própria. Repare que a função imprimenumeros chama-se a si própria até retornar de vez. Ou seja imprimenumeros(3) --chama--> imprimenumeros(2) --chama--> imprimenumeros(1) --chama--> imprimenumeros(0).

while(condição) é considerado iteração, onde vc não chama nenhuma função mais que uma vez, esta resolve logo o seu problema usando ciclos (como while ou for) até chegar ao fim do problema. Vou editar o código acima para lhe dar o exemplo de iteração :)

Comment: Não entendi, porque quando digito 1 o resultado é 0 e 1, quando digito 2 o resultado é 0, 1 e 2. O exercício pedi para que fale se o número é primo ou não.